# Change order of Hyhperlink under Multiple lines of text (Enhanced rich text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, hyperlink, sharepoint-2013

I am having a column Language which is Multiple lines of text - Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks) in SharePoint.

In this column, there can be 2 or more Hyperlinks (see the below image)

The requirement is that when a page load, I will have to read the Url and accordingly order the Hyperlink in the Language Column.

For example:

- Suppose if the URL contains EN, the the Hyperlink should be: EN DE

- Suppose if the URL contains DE, the the Hyperlink should be: DE EN

Would it be possible to achieve that using Javascript or similar technology at browser level ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Could you give some hints of how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (selectedLang = ENlang)
{
    $(DElang).insertAfter($(ENlang));
}else{
    $(ENlang).insertAfter($(DElang));
}
```

This could be the logic if you put your DOM elements in variables.

*(used JQuery)*

**...**

***And here is your complete solution:***

run the code snippet and see it working.

```js
var ENlang = 'ENlang';
var DElang = 'DElang';
var selectedLang;


  
  $('.lang').on('click', function(){
    
    selectedLang = $(this);
    
    if(selectedLang.hasClass('ENlang'))
      {
        $('.DElang').insertAfter($('.ENlang'));
      }else{
        $('.ENlang').insertAfter($('.DElang'));
      }
    
    selectedLang = null;
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a class="DElang lang" href="#"> DE </a> 
  <a class="ENlang lang" href="#"> EN </a>
</div>
```

Comment: When I try to get the Html of that specific column of each line, here is my code: $(".ms-rtestate-field")[0];

Comment: <div class="ms-rtestate-field" dir="">
      <a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/processes/PD-Docs/01860550%20GPM_S5-3_Ziele-Massnahmen.pdf">DE </a>
      <a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Processes/PD-Docs/01860550%20GPM_S5-3_Aims-Actions.pdf">EN </a>
      </div>
</div>

Comment: i do not get it but - just do something like `var ENlang = $('.your-lang-elem');`

Comment: How to get the first href and second href using Jquery ?

Comment: so, was it useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111098/discussion-between-ceylan-mumun-kocabas-and-user3674148).